# Stuck on a possible greedy problem

Tags: algorithms

I am currently dealing with a problem that I believe to be a Greedy releated problem and I'm trying to find some similar problems in order to solve it. I would like to have some hints or resources to study because I'm stuck on it. The text is:

You are tasked with creating a competitive programming squad, selecting students from schools around France. There are $n$ schools in total and every school $i$ has $g_i ≥ 0$ girls and $b_i ≥ 0$ boys. You need to select exactly $k$ students from each school, but be careful: the total number of girls and boys need to be as close as possible. In particular, you need
to select $b^*_i$ boys and $g^*_i$ girls from each school $i$, respecting that 0 ≤ $g^*_i$ ≤ $g_i$
, 0 ≤ $b^*_i$ ≤ $b_i$ and $g^*_i$ + $b^*_i$ = $k$, in order to minimize:

$ | \sum_{i=1}^{n} g^*_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} b^*_i|$

You are guaranteed that for every school $i$, we have $b_i$ + $g_i$ ≥ $k$

Provide an algorithm that computes the $g^*_i$ and $b^*_i$ in polynomial time. Prove its correctness and analyze its run time.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Firstly I tried a dynamic programming approach but I really don't know how approach the problem. I got it but maybe it's my lack of knowledge. If you can share some study materials or something it would be great.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.  This is required: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a dynamic programming solution in linear time.

For $i$ a school, denote $r_i$ to be the range that the value $g^*_i - b^*_i$ can take. For example, if $k = 4$, $g_i = 7$ and $b_i = 2$, then the choices can be $(g^*_i, b^*_i) \in \{(4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 2)\}$. Therefore, $r_i = [0, 4]$. (For convenience, you could consider the range of $\left\lfloor \frac{g^*_i-b^*_i}{2}\right\rfloor$ to get consecutives values.)

Then, define $R_i$ to be the range that the value $\sum\limits_{j=1}^i(g^*_j-b^*_j)$ can take. Knowing $R_{i-1}$ and $r_i$, the range $R_i$ can easily be computed.

Given $(g_i)$ and $(b_i)$ for $i\in\{1, …, n\}$, we want to know the value $x\in R_n$ that minimize $|x|$ (either $0$ or $1$ if it is in $R_n$, depending on the parity of $nk$, or one of the two bounds of $R_n$ otherwise). You can compute the exacts values of $g^*_i$ and $b^*_i$ starting from $i = n$ and going backward.

Comment: "Then, define $R_i$ to be the range that the value $\sum\limits_{j=1}^i(g^*_j-b^*_j)$ can take. Knowing $R_{i-1}$ and $r_i$, the range $R_i$ can easily be computed." Let's say that $r_i$ = k ,  then we will have to do $R_{i-1}$ *k updates to get $R_i$ . Doesn't this mean that the total time taken would be O(k^n) , because there are n schools ?

Comment: $r_i$ is an interval, not an integer, and so is $R_i$. If $r_i = [x_i, y_i]$ and $R_{i-1} = [X_{i-1}, Y_{i-1}]$, then $R_i = [x_i + X_{i-1}, y_i + Y_{i-1}]$, it is computed in constant time.